# Coffeescript equivalent to On Document Ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to use Coffeescript, but I am having a problem on my web application. Its methods are not called until I reload the page.

I think that what is missing is the `$(document).ready(function () {` part, but I couldn't find how to do it in the web.

**file_name.js** (works great)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click', '.add_fields', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  });
});
```

**file_name.coffee** (doesn't work)

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Coffeescript is just fancy Javascript. "On document ready" is not a feature of Javascript language, but feature of the browser or jQuery library. So, when in doubt, just write same Javascript code with block indentation instead of curly brackets, and replacing `function()` with `->`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready ->
```

See example at https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/master/documentation/site/docs.coffee#L16